# How to fail a Jenkins Job upon runtime failure of a docker process?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

My jenkins job triggers a docker process to run.

My docker process may exit depending upon any conditional logic and termination of CMD bash script.

Once exited, I wish my Jenkins job to fail immediately.

The logic I can think is to exit 1; in bash script upon poll checking the docker status say every 4 secs to fail the Jenkins job.

I understand that this is not an ideal solution as the Jenkins job would fail after 2 secs and not immediately. Also, such polling is resource  hungry.

I wish to know if there are better solutions or plugin i can use to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you read the status_code of the docker run command? That way you should able to decide whether it has return 0 or some other value. Based on that you could decide the completion of the job.